# How to wrap timing method around a method call

Tags: java

How to wrap timing method around a method call, is there a simple way to wrap StopWatch

```
for (Foo foo : foos) {
    StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
    sw.start();
    someService.processFoo(foo);
    sw.stop();
    log.trace("saved foo in {} msecs", sw.getTotalTimeMillis());
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem with the current approach? Are looking for a generic solution to measure execution time for anything?

Comment: @Chaosfire feels more verbose, some kind of wrapper which will help us what we want to measure

Comment: Why not just a _class_?

Answer (score 1):

If your service implements an interface, you can use a proxy implementing this interface:

```
public class TimerProxy {
    private final Object delegate;
    
    public TimerProxy(Object delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public <T> T getInterface(Class<T> intf) {
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(loader, new Class<?>[] {intf},
                (pxy, method, args) -> {
            return execute(method, args);
        });
        return intf.cast(proxy);
    }

    private Object execute(Method method, Object[] args) {
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
        sw.start();
        try {
            return method.invoke(delegate, args);
        } finally {
            sw.stop();
            log.trace("Method call {} in {} msecs",
                    method.getName(), sw.getTotalTimeMillis());
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a service that implements interface `Service` you would do:

```
Service service = ...;
Service proxy = new TimerProxy(service).getInterface(Service.class);
```

Then you can use `proxy` instead of `service` to have the duration of the method calls loggged.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Foo foo : foos) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    someService.processFoo(foo);
    long delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    log.trace("saved foo in {} msecs", delta);
}
```

Note that if you're primarily trying to measure how fast your java code is running, it's not that simple. You'll get wildly misleading numbers, especially for relatively fast tasks. If that's what you want to do, [read this tutorial on how to use JMH](https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your method call in runnable and create a utility like `logTaskTime` as methodWrapper for each task you wish to log

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo[] foos = new Foo[0];
        for (Foo foo : foos) {
            Runnable runnable = () -> {/*someService.processFoo(foo);*/};
            logTaskTime(runnable);
        }
    }

    private static void logTaskTime(Runnable runnable) {
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
        sw.start();
        runnable.run();
        sw.stop();
        System.out.println(sw.getTime());
       // log.trace("saved foo in {} msecs", sw.getTotalTimeMillis());
    }
```

I hope as mentioned in other answers, this is not being used to measure performance for java code.

Comment: can't use Runnable

Comment: Why not? As a note,here runnable is being used as lambda which does not need any input and does not return any output.We are not using it for multithreading if that is the concern

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper that executes the task and measure execution time

```
public class TaskTimer {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TaskTimer.class);

  private final Runnable taskToMeasure;

  public TaskTimer(Runnable taskToMeasure) {
    this.taskToMeasure = taskToMeasure;
  }

  public void doTask() {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    this.taskToMeasure.run();
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    long millis = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(end - start);
    LOGGER.trace("Task finished in {} millis", millis);
  }
}
```

Then wrap any task in it:

```
TaskTimer task1 = new TaskTimer(() -> someService.processFoo(foo));
task1.doTask();
TaskTimer task2 = new TaskTimer(() -> otherServide.processBar(bar));
task2.doTask();
TaskTimer task3 = new TaskTimer(() -> thirdService.processFooBar(fooBar));
task3.doTask();
//etc.
```

Keep in mind this is quite simple and naive way to measure execution time, so it won't be absolutely accurate.